# MongoDB Shell - Add new field to all the documents from an existing field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to create a TTL for all the existing documents in the collection, we have a field in all the document as String type - `"OrigDate": "2020-03-24"`

Now I want to add another filed "updatedAt" based on this field, I tried the below in mongo shell but not working -

```
db.SHOP.update(
    {},
    {
     $set:{
            "updatedAt": { "$toDate": "$OrigDate"}
        }
    },
    false,
    true
)
```

This gives the below exception - The dollar ($) prefixed field '$toDate' in 'updatedAt.$toDate' is not valid for storage

Please help

Comment: In `updatedAt` you want to store current date or any other precised date?

Comment: I want to use the data available in the "OrigDate" item which is of type String. I want to convert it to Date using $toDate()

Comment: You have to use an aggregation to refer to the existing field. If you have MongoDB version 4.2, you can use the aggregation within the `update` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation to make the new field from the existing field value, and then update it to the collection. You must use an aggregation to refer to an existing field from the collection's document.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { updatedAt: { "$toDate": "$OrigDate"} } }
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { updatedAt: doc.updatedAt } } ) )
```

This following update accepts an aggregation pipeline to specify the modifications to be applied on the collection documents: [Update with an Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline). Note this feature is available with MongoDB version 4.2 or later only.

```
db.test.updateMany(
  { },
  [
      { $set: { updatedAt: { "$toDate": "$OrigDate"} } }
  ]
)
```